# R plot graphics statistics people same birthday

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to code the birthday problem in R using the plot . I've wrote the code the problem is that I get an error with that .

Any idea is welcomed .Thank you very much .

> ***Edit edit I've changed the code :***

```
paradoxe_anniversaires <- function(n){
  N<-365
  produit = 1 ;

    for(i in 1:(n-1))
    produit<-produit*(1 -(i/N) )

 resultat <- (1 - produit)
 return (resultat)
}
graphe_anniv <- function(){
  x<- c(1:100)
  y<-paradoxe_anniversaires(x)
  plot(x,y)
}
```

but this time I have Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:(n - 1) :

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code implementation, rather than mathematics.

Comment: ok i see and where I should put it? in what forum because now I've changed the code thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with taking the factorial of 365.  When I just try to run `factorial(365)` in R, it returns the same errors about the value out of range in 'gammafn'.  I ran your code with a smaller value for `N` and it works just fine.  It seems to work fine with values of `N` which are less than or equal to 170.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have to do it with N = 365 to test the paradox of birthdays I've edited the code but now I have a different error

Comment: @anamaria After doing some reading, it looks like you can work around this by using the `lgamma()` function.  This returns the log of the gamma function, and will return results for values greater than 170.  So to get `factorial(365)` you could use `lgamma(366)` and this will return the log of factorial(365).

Comment: Thank you so much but I've tried to use the wikipedia formule and I don't know if you have seen that I've put a edit in my post with another error I have